# TikZ: pgfutil-common: pgfutil@in@ - how does it work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, strings, text-manipulation

Having been writing small lib for TikZ, I tried to use this macro in order to search for `@`. Code compiled, but the result was `false`, despite that I was sure it was in tested string. So, I decided to look into an implementation of this macro, but it breaks my brain by self-recursive usage of `pgfutil@in@` and `pgfutil@in@@`. Could someone explain how that manages to work? And, furthermore, if it can be changed to make search for `@` applicable?

```
% pgfutil@in@

\newif\ifpgfutil@in@

% Usage:
% \pgfutil@in@{one}{three two one}
% \ifpgfutil@in@
%   -> will be true!
% \else
% \fi
%
% \pgfutil@in@{,}{1234,456567}
% \ifpgfutil@in@
%   -> will be true!
% \else
% \fi
\def\pgfutil@in@#1#2{%
 \def\pgfutil@in@@##1#1##2##3\pgfutil@in@@{%
  \ifx\pgfutil@in@##2\pgfutil@in@false\else\pgfutil@in@true\fi}%
 \pgfutil@in@@#2#1\pgfutil@in@\pgfutil@in@@}
```

I expect that there must be some way to tweak it by means of `catcode`...

**EDIT**:

Usage example:

```
\edef \pgf@marshal{\noexpand \pgfutil@in@{@}{\tikz@temp}}%
\pgf@marshal%
```

**EDIT 2**:

I discovered that using `\pgfutil@in@{@}{\tikz@temp}` from document context with set `\makeatletter` I don't encounter any problems even with searching for `@` directly.

Having investigated into how TikZ includes libraries, I found that it saves category code for `@`, sets it to `11`, includes library, then restores the category code for `@`. So it's ok to define macroses with `@` in the name.

But before executing `\pgfutil@in@{@}{\tikz@temp}` (now inside some macros in my library) I do:

```
\c@pgf@counta = \catcode`\@%
\showthe \c@pgf@counta%
```

and see that `pdflatex` outputs `12`. Hmmm... I guess this is due to that macroses in my library are just read and saved for later use. They're executed inside the `document` environment, when the category code for `@` is already `12`. Made such a suggestion I tried to put `\makeatletter` just before the `\begin{document}` and it worked like a charm!

So, is there a way to somehow alter the category code for `@` just in place where it should be `11` by the time of execution?

Another suggestion is that by the time the macros is read the category code for `@` is `11`, but when being executed, the expanded value of `\tikz@temp` contains `@` of category code `12`. So, they will never match, unless I do `\makeatletter` at the document context.

Comment: I think an example of how you used it might be handy: I suspect you got the catcode of `@` wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Joseph: I edited my question in order to include example of usage.

Comment: @Dmitry: I've edited the answer to cover that case

Comment: @Dmitry: The issue of category codes for `@` really deserves a separate question. I suggest you post one, linking to this question for context. (We like to keep each question focussed, where possible.)

Comment: @Joseph: I've just started to compose one :) Also, there will be the minimalistic example, so that you're able to see what's happening.

Comment: Further discussing has evaluated into separate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17393/changing-catcode-for-commercial-at-inside-a-macro-to-get-it-matched-in-patter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macros are pretty simple and use standard TeX argument delimiting. The fact that the same macro names are reused makes the code a little less clear, but does not alter the effect. To make life easier, we could write the same concept out using some additional markers:

```
\def\pgfutil@in@#1#2{%
  \def\pgfutil@in@@##1#1##2##3\pgfutil@stop{%
    \ifx\pgfutil@marker##2\pgfutil@in@false\else\pgfutil@in@true\fi
   }%
 \pgfutil@in@@#2#1\pgfutil@marker\pgfutil@stop
}
\def\pgfutil@marker{\pgfutil@marker}
```

The idea is then that the auxiliary function `\pgfutil@in@@` is defined so that its argument has to contain `#1`, and will be stopped by `\pgfutil@stop` (`\pgfutil@in@@` in the original).

`\pgfutil@in@@` is then used so that it will *always* be followed by at least one `#1`, which will be immediately followed by a marker (`\pgfutil@in@` in the original, `\pgfutil@marker` in my version). If `#1` is not in `#2`, then `##1` will be `#2`, `##2` will be the marker and `##3` will be empty. The `\ifx` test will be TRUE, and the flag is set FALSE.  On the other hand, if `#1` *is* in `#2`, then `##1` will be the part of `#2` before the first `#1`, `##2` will *not* be the marker and `##3` will tidy up. The `\ifx` will be FALSE and so the flag will be set TRUE.

This all relies on the *category code* of `#1` matching the occurrence in `#2`. We are talking about `@`, and so it's possible to do something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\myfunction#1{%
  \pgfutil@in@{@}{#1}%
  ...
}
\makeatother
```

and to get the wrong result. That's because the hard-coded `@` is a 'letter' while any in `#1` will (probably) be 'other'. That can be avoided using a bit of `\lowercase` trickery.

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\lccode`\*=`\@\relax
\lowercase{%
  \endgroup
  \def\myfunction#1{%
    \pgfutil@in@{*}{#1}%
    ...
  } 
}
\makeatother
```

where the idea is that `*` acts as a substitute for `@`: it has category code 'other' but is turned into a `@` by the `\lowercase`.

---

For the edited question, the correct approach would be

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\*=`\@\relax
\lowercase{%
  \endgroup
  \edef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\pgfutil@in@{*}{\tikz@temp}}%
}
\pgf@marshal
```

Comment: at the top of `pgfutil-common.tex` there's statement `\catcode\`\@=11\relax`. And then there's a plenty of macroses, which contain `@` in the name. So, it looks unnecessary to `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @Dmitry: My assumption was that you were using things in a document context, hence the guards.

Comment: I should add that the general point is the same: if `@` is a letter, you need to take care when searching for `@` as an 'other' character.

Comment: please read **EDIT 2** section of my question. Thanks for the current help and in advance.