# Testing for commercial at (@) in a string

Tags: conditionals, strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing catcode for commercial at (@) inside a macro to get it matched in pattern.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17393/changing-catcode-for-commercial-at-inside-a-macro-to-get-it-matched-in-patte)

I want to test whether a string contains the @ sign.  I came up with the following piece of code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@testat#1@#2\@nil{%
  \def\@cdr{#2}
  \ifx\@cdr\@empty #1#2: does not have at\else #1#2: has at\fi}
\def\hasat#1{\@testat#1@\@nil}
\makeatother
```

Now this works fine if the document is written with `\makeatletter`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\test[1]{#1}
\test{\hasat{linear@ set@}}
\hasat{linear@ set@}
\hasat{linear set}
```

all work fine.  But without the `\makeatletter`, this fails miserably.  If instead I define:

```
\def\@hasat#1{\@testat#1@\@nil\makeatother}
\def\hasat{\makeatletter\@hasat}
```

then only the `\hasat` which is not in a `\test` works for some reason.

Any help welcome!

Comment: Dammit.  Stackexchange now pops up the relevant related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17393/changing-catcode-for-commercial-at-inside-a-macro-to-get-it-matched-in-patte .  Feel free to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Don't define `\@cdr` as part of your macro; it's already a macro used in the kernel and redefining it can lead to obscure errors.

Comment: Strange, I would not consider this as a duplicate of the other one. If we really think they're "identical", I would say that this one is better and provides a better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect if the given string contains a character with the `xstring` package:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\HasAt}[3]{%
    \StrPosition{#1}{@}[\Position]
    #1 \IfEq{\Position}{0}{#3}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\HasAt{ancd@foo.bar}{does}{does not} contains the @ symbol.

\HasAt{ancdfoo.bar}{does}{does not} contains the @ symbol.

\end{document}
```